# Orchestration of batch job into a microservices architecture - SCDF

Tags: spring-batch, microservices, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

i have a microservice which he have 5 embeded batch job that runs every night at 00:00 , i want to outsource those batches using Spring Cloud DataFlow , my questions are :

-how can i connect SCDF to the actual microservice for local deployment 
-is there an alternative to get a scheduler in SCDF for 
local deployment

Comment: Have you tried something so far?

Comment: SCDF launches/orchestrates microservies, it does not talk to ones that are already running.  We need more insights into your use case to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Cloud Data Flow uses Spring Cloud Skipper to deploy and launch.
This question seems similar to your query. [Does spring-cloud-dataflow provide support for scheduling applications defined as tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991956/does-spring-cloud-dataflow-provide-support-for-scheduling-applications-defined-a)